# Is it possible to send bold text in JSON push notification body using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notification to IOS and Android devices. I would like to send some text in message body, which has a part of it bold. That's how my JSON looks like now for android push notifications:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "body":"Some plain text THIS TEXT SHOULD BE BOLD some plain text"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to see the message in my push notification like this: "Some plain text **THIS TEXT SHOULD BE BOLD** some plain text"

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send as [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) and make your Android client parse it, so your message would be something like

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "body":"Some plain text **THIS TEXT SHOULD BE BOLD** some plain text"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not supported on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to change the font characteristics for notification type messages with FCM.  If you need to do some special work to create a notification, you should instead send a message with a data payload, and deal with its contents yourself.